# Local IP and external IP setup for React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am connecting to Node on React. Every time I am outside of my home server, I need to change the local IP config to the external IP config. And, is there any way that I can set two IP addresses (one for local IP address and another one for external IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you mean when your are outside, in your React app you need to change the IP to access your Node server. If I am right then you can move forward.

You can make use of environment variable `process.env`.
In you `package.json` under `scripts` add something like this:
`"office": "IP=\"THE_IP\" npm start"`. Then from your app, you can access the IP value like this `process.env.IP`.

Now, when you run your app from outside you would run this command: `npm run office`.

If your are using windows: `set "IP=abcdef" && npm start`.

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

For Node.js application -

You can add ecosystem.config.js file into your project and add the developement and production URL and other variables there. Then you can start your server via pm2.

For developement you can use command - 
pm2 start

For production you can use command - 
pm2 start --env production

For detailed explaination you can follow this link : https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/

And for React application

You can simply make a file named .env and define your URL and other environment variables there.